# Iterando multiples resultados de promesas

Tags: javascript, typescript, promesas, angular8, iteradores

Tengo una pregunta con respecto a este codigo.

```js
 let results = [1, 2 ,3 4]
 randomArray.forEach( async (e, i) => {
        externalApi(e).subscribe(async ({data}) => {
          results.push(data);
          console.log("result", e);
        }, (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        });
    });
```

Como se ve estoy *iterando* sobre un **array** para obtener multiples resultados de un api y *almacenarlos* en `results`, en teoria funciona pero debido a que la llamada al api es una promesa, el `results.push(data)`, no se va a ejecutar inmediatamente, por lo que esperaria 2 cosas.

1. **Que results no tuviese valores al terminar la iteracion**
2. **Despues de un tiempo results almacenara los valores obtenidos del api**

Esto en teoria ocurre pero obtengo estos resultados:

> //*console results*
>
> $"result, 1"
>
> $"result, 2"
>
> $"result, 2"
>
> $"result, 1"
>
> $"result, 3"
>
> $"result, 4"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto me deja confundido por que, si bien se ejecutando de forma `asyncrona` el trabajo, parece que la *iteracion* esta enviando peticiones multiples por cada iteracion o es lo que entiendo.

> Es decir, esperaria resultados despues de un tiempo, pero no multiples resultados de lo que creo es solo una iteracion.

En conclusion quisiera saber:

1. **¿Por que es que sucede esto, hay algo que no estoy entendiendo aqui sobre las funciones `async`?**
2. **¿Cual es la forma correcta de implementar la respuesta promise dentro de un iterador?**

Comment: ¿En qué punto es que ves el resultado que has puesto aquí?

Comment: el resultado varia, despues de un tiempo mi problema es que es que obtengo multiples respuestas por iteracion

Comment: Parece que lo que devuelve `externalApi` es un `Observable`, ¿cierto?

Comment: parece que si puedo usar el *pipe* y *subcribe*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al inicio eso también me confundía, puesto que no entendía qué eran los `Observables` en *Angular*, pero luego cuando los entendí, me di cuenta de que eran muy, muy útiles.

Resulta y pasa que un `Observable` es una clase que permite crear eventos personalizados, eventos que pueden venir de otros eventos y que quedan linqueados a otras funciones (hasta que nos desuscribamos de ellos).

Por ejemplo podemos usar:

```
Observable.from
```

Para crear eventos personalizados que provienen de otros de fábrica.
O eventos creados por nosotros:

```
messages = [];

constructor() {
   this.getMessages().subscribe(message => {
      this.messages.push(message);
   })
}

getMessages() {

   let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket.on("message", data => {
         observer.next(data);
      })
   });

   return observable;
}
```

**Este código no es mio, fue tomado de:**
[Ionic Realtime Chat with Socket.io](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGjRiinm67o)

Resulta y pasa, que como todo evento, cuando alguno de estos se dispara, automáticamente se ejecuta aquello que esta ligado al evento y por cada vez que se ejecuta se retorna un valor que puede ser o no diferente:

```
Observable.next()
```

Cuando nosotros nos subscribimos a los cambios:

```
Observable.subscribe()
```

Le estamos diciendo que cada vez que se ejecute `Observable.next` llame al cuerpo del evento con el último valor que nos devolvió `Observable.next`.

¿Pero qué pasa?, que aparentemente con cada iteración te estas subscribiendo a un nuevo `Observable`:

```
let results = [1, 2, 3, 4]
 randomArray.forEach( async (e, i) => {
     externalApi(e).subscribe(async ({data}) => {
        results.push(data);
        console.log("result", e);
     }, (error) => {
        console.log(error)
 });
});
```

Y aunque un observable no debería afectar al otro, puede ser que este observable se este ejecutando al crearse, por este motivo en cada iteración los resultados son tan diferentes, por que tus observables también están afectando a tu variable `results`.

Haciendo que ya no `1` si no `6` o `7` observables estén subscritos al mismo evento (o por lo menos al mismo cuerpo del evento), el evento el cual cambia la data de tu variable `results`.

**Conclusión:**

No son las `promises` ni el `async`, este resultado es culpa de los `observables` y el `subscribe`.

Lo cual es natural, puesto que normalmente no nos suscribimos varias veces a un mismo evento... lo ideal sería suscribirnos solo una vez ya que ya quedaría ligado a nuestro observable hasta que decidamos cancelarlo:

```
Observable.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Te me has adelantado, @Riven. Efectivamente, el `Observable` es algo que confunde a veces a la gente que usa el módulo `HttpClient` de *Angular*, ya que los `Observable` de ese módulo "triggerean" una sola vez. Cuando se usa *rxjs* en otros contextos donde emiten varios valores, pasan este tipo de "inconsistencias".

Comment: Agregaría a la respuesta que si sólo se espera un único valor de `externalApi`, en vez de suscribirse y desuscribirse, se puede convertir a `Promise` con el método `toPromise` para resolverla una única vez y obtener un único valor.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya respondió @Riven, se trata de observables y no promesas.
Si quieres iterar las respuesta del servicio de forma síncrona, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
let results = [1, 2, 3, 4];
randomArray.forEach( async (e, i) => {
    try {
        const data = await externalApi(e).toPromise();
        results.push(data);
        console.log("result", e);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error("result", e);
    }
});
```

El `HttpClient` de *Angular* y todos los observables incluyen [un método que permite convertirlos en promesas](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise).
Solo ten en cuenta que con esto solo obtendrás la primera respuesta del observable. Si se trata de un observable que responderá en multiples ocasiones, no te recomiendo hacer esto.